Are most prime numbers symmetric?
Let $f_n(x):= \prod_{p|n} f_p(x)^{v_p(n)}$ for natural numbers $n$ and for primes $p$:
$$f_2(x):=x, f_p(x):=1+\prod_{q|p-1}f_q(x)^{v_q(p-1)} \text{ for } p > 2$$
Then: $n = \operatorname{rad}(n)\iff f_n(x)$ is a separable polynomial.
It can also be proven that:
$f_n(x)$ is irreducible $\iff$ $n$ is a prime number.
Hence one might use these polynomials as a bridge between natural numbers and say Algebra / Galois theory.
Let us call a number "separable" or "square-free" if it is of the form $n = \operatorname{rad}(n)$.
If $n$ is a separable number, then it has property $X$ if the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(f_n(x)/\mathbb{Q})$ has property $X$.
Hence we might say, a separable number is "abelian, cyclic, solvable, symmetric" if the corresponding Galois group is such.
I have computed with GP/PARI-SageMath for some primes the Galois groups, and it occurred to me, that with increasing primes $p$ the Galois groups get more and more the symmetric group. Since it is known that most random polynomials have symmetric Galois group, and it is also known (by Landaus interpretation of the Prime number theorem with the summatory Liouville function), that prime numbers behave like random values, one would expect, after seeing the empirical data, that most prime numbers have symmetric Galois group or are symmetric. This observation aligns with the empirical observation that primes behave randomly.
Here is a list computed with SageMath:
2 [1, 1, 1, "S1"]
3 [1, 1, 1, "S1"]
5 [2, -1, 1, "S2"]
7 [2, -1, 1, "S2"]
11 [6, -1, 1, "S3"]
13 [6, -1, 1, "S3"]
17 [4, 1, 1, "E(4) = 2[x]2"]
19 [6, -1, 1, "S3"]
23 [24, -1, 1, "S4"]
29 [24, -1, 1, "S4"]
31 [4, -1, 1, "C(4) = 4"]
37 [8, -1, 1, "D(4)"]
41 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
43 [8, -1, 1, "D(4)"]
47 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
53 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
59 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
61 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
67 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
71 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
73 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
79 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
83 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
89 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
97 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
101 [12, -1, 1, "D(6) = S(3)[x]2"]
103 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
107 [48, -1, 1, "2S_4(6) = [2^3]S(3) = 2 wr S(3)"]
109 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
113 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
127 [10, 1, 1, "D(5) = 5:2"]
131 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
137 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
139 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
149 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
151 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
157 [72, -1, 1, "F_36(6):2 = [S(3)^2]2 = S(3) wr 2"]
163 [120, -1, 1, "S5"]
167 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
173 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
179 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
181 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
191 [72, -1, 1, "F_36(6):2 = [S(3)^2]2 = S(3) wr 2"]
193 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
197 [72, -1, 1, "F_36(6):2 = [S(3)^2]2 = S(3) wr 2"]
199 [72, -1, 1, "F_36(6):2 = [S(3)^2]2 = S(3) wr 2"]
211 [72, -1, 1, "F_36(6):2 = [S(3)^2]2 = S(3) wr 2"]
223 [48, -1, 1, "2S_4(6) = [2^3]S(3) = 2 wr S(3)"]
227 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
229 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
233 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
239 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
241 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
251 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
257 [8, 1, 2, "4[x]2"]
263 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
269 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
271 [48, -1, 1, "2S_4(6) = [2^3]S(3) = 2 wr S(3)"]
277 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
281 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
283 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
293 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
307 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
311 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
313 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
317 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
331 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
337 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
347 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
349 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
353 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
359 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
367 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
373 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
379 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
383 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
389 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
397 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
401 [64, 1, 29, "E(8):D_8=[2^3]D(4)"]
409 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
419 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
421 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
431 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
433 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
439 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
443 [384, -1, 44, "[2^4]S(4)"]
449 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
457 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
461 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
463 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
467 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
479 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
487 [720, -1, 1, "S6"]
491 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
499 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
503 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
509 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
521 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
523 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
541 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
547 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
557 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
563 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
569 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
571 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
577 [1152, -1, 47, "[S(4)^2]2"]
587 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
593 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
599 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
601 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
607 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
613 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
617 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
619 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
631 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
641 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
643 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
647 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
653 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
659 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
661 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
673 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
677 [1152, -1, 47, "[S(4)^2]2"]
683 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
691 [384, -1, 44, "[2^4]S(4)"]
701 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
709 [1152, -1, 47, "[S(4)^2]2"]
719 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
727 [1152, -1, 47, "[S(4)^2]2"]
733 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
739 [128, -1, 35, "[2^4]D(4)"]
743 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
751 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
757 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
761 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
769 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
773 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
787 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
797 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
809 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
811 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
821 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
823 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
827 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
829 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
839 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
853 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
857 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
859 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
863 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
877 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
881 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
883 [5040, -1, 1, "S7"]
887 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
907 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
911 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
919 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
929 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
937 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
941 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
947 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
953 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
967 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
971 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
977 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]
983 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
991 [40320, -1, 50, "S8"]
997 [362880, -1, 34, "S9"]

How would one approach to prove such an observation?
Thanks for your help.
Edit: Despite the observation of the symmetric group, therer seem to be a class of primes which is very structured:
For primes $p>2$ of the form $f_p(x^2) = f_{f_p(4)}(x)$ I think I can prove that each of the prime divisors $q>2$ of $p-1$ is again of this form: $f_q(x^2) = f_{f_q(4)}(x)$. Using Theorem 6.1 from here, the Galois group of those polynomials is transitive and imprimitive:
Theorem 6.1: Imprimitivity and $f(x) = g(h(x))$
Theorem
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 0, and let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $k[x]$ with root set $\Omega_f$ in an algebraic closure. Furthermore, let $K = k(\Omega_f)$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ and $G = \mathrm{Gal}(K/k)$ the Galois group. The following statements are equivalent:

There exist polynomials $g(x) \in K[x]$ and $h(x) \in k[x]$, both of degree $\geq 2$, such that
$$
   f(x) = g(h(x)).
   $$

(a) $G$ is imprimitive with a block $\Delta$,
(b) If $H = \{\sigma \in G \mid \sigma(\Delta) = \Delta\}$, $F$ is the fixed field of $H$, and $b \in \Delta$, then
$$
   \mathrm{Irr}(b, F, x) = h(x) - a
   $$
for some polynomial $h(x) \in k[x]$ and $a \in F$.


Thus we have for such primes $p>2$ with $f_p(x^2) = f_{f_p(4)}(x)$ a very strong condition on the primes $q>2$ dividing $p-1$ which leads to conditions on the Galois group being
transitive and imprimitive for $p$ and for $q$. Yet it seems that the number of primes $\pi_4(n):=$ number of such primes $p$ with $p \le n$ is approximately $n^{3/8}$.
Here are some $p$ for which $f_p(x^2) = f_{f_p(4)}(x)$ with $f_p(4)$ and $p-1$ factored:
p f_p(4) p-1
2 2^2 3
3 5 2^2
5 17 2^4
17 257 2^8
19 101 2^2 * 5^2
37 401 2^4 * 5^2
61 1361 2^4 * 5 * 17
73 1601 2^6 * 5^2
191 6869 2^2 * 17 * 101
229 8081 2^4 * 5 * 101
257 65537 2^16
271 8501 2^2 * 5^3 * 17
409 82241 2^6 * 5 * 257
457 32321 2^6 * 5 * 101
733 108881 2^4 * 5 * 1361

Edit: Trying to connect these polynomials to the prime number theorem, we might proceed as follows:
For each prime number $p$ let $x_p$ be a variable and let us write:
$$x_{\mathbb{P}}:=(x_p)_{ p \in \mathbb{P}}$$
we define the multivariate polynomials :
$$F_n(x_{\mathbb{P}}):= \prod_{p|n}f_p(x_p)^{v_p(n)}$$
Thus when we set all $x_p$ to $x$, this gives the polynomial above $f_n(x)$ back. Let now $\alpha_p$ be a root of $f_p(x_p)+1$, which means that :
$$f_p(\alpha_p)=-1$$
Substituting we get:
$$F_n( \alpha_{\mathbb{P}}) = \prod_{p|n}(-1)^{v_p(n)} = (-1)^{\Omega(n)} =: \lambda(n)$$
So with this observation and having Landau's interpretation of the PNT in mind, we can define:
$$S_n( x_{\mathbb{P}}):=\sum_{k=1}^n F_k(x_{\mathbb{P}})$$
with the property that:
$$S_n(\alpha_{\mathbb{P}}) = \sum_{k=1}^n F_k(\alpha_{\mathbb{P}}) = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda(k) =: L(n)$$
Hence it follows that:
$$\text{ PNT} \iff 0 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} L(n) =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} S_n(\alpha_{\mathbb{P}})$$
which suggests a study of the polynomials:
$$f_p(x)+1$$
and how the roots $\alpha_p$ are distributed and questions like, what properties do the multivariate polynomials and maybe its algebraic varieties of $F_n(x_{\mathbb{P}})$ and $S_n(x_{\mathbb{P}})$ have?
It seems that for $n>1$ the ideal generated by $S_n$ is a prime ideal:
n =  1
S_n =  1
is_prime : False
n =  2
S_n =  x_2 + 1
is_prime : True
n =  3
S_n =  x_2 + x_3 + 2
is_prime : True
n =  4
S_n =  x_2^2 + x_2 + x_3 + 2
is_prime : True
n =  5
S_n =  x_2^2 + x_5^2 + x_2 + x_3 + 3
is_prime : True
n =  6
S_n =  x_2^2 + x_2*x_3 + x_5^2 + 2*x_2 + x_3 + 3
is_prime : True
n =  7
S_n =  x_2^2 + x_2*x_3 + x_5^2 + x_7^2 + 2*x_2 + x_3 + x_7 + 4
is_prime : True
n =  8
S_n =  x_2^3 + x_2^2 + x_2*x_3 + x_5^2 + x_7^2 + 2*x_2 + x_3 + x_7 + 4
is_prime : True
n =  9
S_n =  x_2^3 + x_2^2 + x_2*x_3 + x_3^2 + x_5^2 + x_7^2 + 2*x_2 + 3*x_3 + x_7 + 5
is_prime : True
n =  10
S_n =  x_2^3 + x_2*x_5^2 + x_2^2 + x_2*x_3 + x_3^2 + x_5^2 + x_7^2 + 3*x_2 + 3*x_3 + x_7 + 5
is_prime : True
n =  11
S_n =  x_11^3 + x_2^3 + x_2*x_5^2 + x_2^2 + x_2*x_3 + x_3^2 + x_5^2 + x_7^2 + x_11 + 3*x_2 + 3*x_3 + x_7 + 6
is_prime : True

Related question: Are there infinitely many $g$- or $m$-primes?

For all sufficiently large $> 100$ numbers $n$ we seem to have $S_n(x)$ is irreducible in $x$ and has Galois group the symmetric group on $\operatorname{floor}(\log(n)/\log(2))$ elements, which would prove that for large $n$ the multivariate polynomials $S_n$ are irreducible.
